# i want to enable the button in two pages using enabled: what is the syntax of that?

Tags: qt, qml

I try to enable the `Button` in the settings tab and help tab.
The code I tried is

```
Button{
    id:buttn
    image:"icons/buttn"
    enabled: { settings.enabled && help.enabled }
    visible: { settings.visible && help.visible}
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: You have one `Button` and want to set it to be active from both, a `settings` page or from a `help` page? If you have enabled it from `settings`, do you want to be able to disable it from the help page, or will you need to use the same page to disable it, from where you have enabled it?

Comment: sorry for my mistake .this is not pages. this are two tabs.when we switch the tab the button should be visible in that tab.no need to be disable. there is syntax mistake in enabled and visible. i want the correct syntax

Comment: Plase include the syntax error message.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is no error message.i tried enabled:{settings.enabled; help.enabled;}    visible: { settings.visible ;help.visible;}
but the button is showing only in one tab.help tab..

Comment: Please post the code, including your tabs e.t.c. If you have only one `Button` this won't show up *in* multiple tabs.